# What is the best way to use Sage

Tags: sage

I am using Sage (or SageMath) for doing some mathematics, and I would like to make it a habit of mine to use it and to teach it to students. However I have an organisational problem on how to use Sage!

As far as I know, there are these options to use Sage:

- on a terminal
- on a notebook

However, I would like to use it writing my code in separated script files well documented and running them on a terminal once it is done. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Hi!  This isn't really a programming question, so you may not get too many answers here.  I suggest either https://matheducators.stackexchange.com if you are asking a question about teaching (and I think that would be in bounds there), or ask.sagemath.org for any and all Sage questions.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are many ways to use Sage - terminal, several notebook types, [standalone Sage cells](https://sagecell.sagemath.org), and embedded Sage cells.  Your last question is also pretty easy if you run things on `.sage` files.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the [SageMath tutorial](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/) which has a section on ways to use SageMath, some alternative lists have been provided as answers to some questions on Ask Sage, such as

- [Ask Sage question 42876: Other than Jupyter notebook is there any other way to use Sage](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/42876)
- [Ask Sage question 34350: Installing on Windows 10](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/34350)

Maybe you would be interested in the

- [Sage-shell-mode for Emacs](https://github.com/sagemath/sage-shell-mode)

or maybe in running Sage in an IDE like PyCharm or Spyder, in which case see

- [Make PyCharm recognise the Sage python interpreter](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/39742)

Note also Tomer Bauer's 2019-06 "Introduction to Sage"
as a Jupyter slideshow available from the

- [Talks and presentations page on the Sage wiki](https://wiki.sagemath.org/Talks)

for another nice way to use Sage in a teaching context.